# How to Save Prediction values for whole data in keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am using pre-trained VGG16 model to classify images located in the folder. Currently, I am able to classify only one single image.

1. How can I modify the code to classify all the images in the folder
2. How can I save the prediction values for each image ?

Below is my code :

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import decode_predictions
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filename = 'cat.jpg'
# load an image in PIL format
original = load_img(filename, target_size=(224, 224))
print('PIL image size',original.size)
plt.imshow(original)
plt.show()

# convert the PIL image to a numpy array
# IN PIL - image is in (width, height, channel)
# In Numpy - image is in (height, width, channel)
numpy_image = img_to_array(original)
plt.imshow(np.uint8(numpy_image))
plt.show()
print('numpy array size',numpy_image.shape)

# Convert the image / images into batch format
# expand_dims will add an extra dimension to the data at a particular axis
# We want the input matrix to the network to be of the form (batchsize, height, width, channels)
# Thus we add the extra dimension to the axis 0.
image_batch = np.expand_dims(numpy_image, axis=0)
print('image batch size', image_batch.shape)
plt.imshow(np.uint8(image_batch[0]))



# prepare the image for the VGG model
processed_image = vgg16.preprocess_input(image_batch.copy())

# get the predicted probabilities for each class
predictions = vgg_model.predict(processed_image)
print (predictions)

# convert the probabilities to class labels
# We will get top 5 predictions which is the default
#label = decode_predictions(predictions)
```

Thank you

Comment: Just list files in your directory and classify them one by one. While doing this you can store your predictions in a list, file, anywhere..

Comment: Thank you Mr.Josef for your valuable reply. Could you please share the code for that or any link showing the code if possible . With huge appreciation.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to list filenames and loop over them. You could use i.e. os.listdir, specifying the input folder. I removed the various imshow or plot chunks of code.

Code below:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import decode_predictions
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
nfiles = os.listdir("./inputfolder") # List filenames

for filename in nfiles: # Enter the loop
    # load an image in PIL format
    original = load_img(filename, target_size=(224, 224))    
    # convert the PIL image to a numpy array
    # IN PIL - image is in (width, height, channel)
    # In Numpy - image is in (height, width, channel)
    numpy_image = img_to_array(original)
    print('numpy array size',numpy_image.shape)

    # Convert the image / images into batch format
    # expand_dims will add an extra dimension to the data at a particular 
axis
    # We want the input matrix to the network to be of the form (batchsize, 
height, width, channels)
    # Thus we add the extra dimension to the axis 0.
    image_batch = np.expand_dims(numpy_image, axis=0)
    print('image batch size', image_batch.shape)

    # prepare the image for the VGG model
    processed_image = vgg16.preprocess_input(image_batch.copy())

    # get the predicted probabilities for each class
    predictions = vgg_model.predict(processed_image)
    print (predictions)

    # convert the probabilities to class labels
    # We will get top 5 predictions which is the default
    #label = decode_predictions(predictions)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mr.FMarazzi,

The folder structure is:

Folder1 : contains the .py file
      Subfolder1: contains some files
              Sub-SubFolder : Contains the images that I need to read them through the loop 



So, Shall I replace this line 

    nfiles = os.listdir("./inputfolder") # List filenames

with 
nfiles = os.listdir("./Subfolder1/Sub-SubFolder") # List filenames

? 

Thank you in advanced